# jQuery executing both branches of an if-else statement in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the following jQuery on a Rails page:

```
$(document).on('click','.reportsArrow', function() {
    if ( $(this).parent().hasClass('reportCollapsed') ) {
      console.log("A");
      $(this).parent().removeClass('reportCollapsed');
    }else{
      $(this).parent().addClass('reportCollapsed');
        console.log("B");
    }
});
```

When I click on an element with `reportsArrow` and without `reportCollapsed`, the log shows

`B`

`A`

Meaning it is executing the `else` part and then executing the `if` part.  I want the function to only be executed once per click, and to only follow one code path.  Why is it being executed twice and how do I stop this?  I should point out that this toggles correctly in the mockups created by the web designer (on HTML/CSS/JS only).  It looks like the problem is Rails related.

EDIT:

We have found a working solution:

```
$('.reportsArrow').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('reportCollapsed');
});
```

Comment: Could you paste the part of the HTML where this functionality is triggered from? It seems to me like there's something causing this behaviour, and it's not your javascript syntax...

Comment: The entire HTML for this page (including js) can be found here: http://pastie.org/private/napvctifydbsr7hjzycxrg

Comment: I can't seem to find where 'commonclass' is located on this page, but I see you've used "javascript:void(0)" in some href, probably to make it clickable. Is this the case for your 'commonclass' as well?

Comment: What I called `commonClass` in my original question is actually `reportsArrow` in my code.

Comment: Could you try this `href="#" onclick="return false;" ` instead of `href="javascript:void(0)"`?

Comment: Good suggestion but I get the same error

Comment: Hmmm... Not making sense... One final suggestion before I give up and tear my diplomas, could you change in your jquery function this `$(document).on('click','.reportsArrow', function()` to this `$('.reportsArrow').click(function ()`?

Comment: Unfortunately your example on pasie.org includes dependencies to local resources. Could you setup a minimal environment with remote dependencies that reproduces the error?

Comment: Ruby Racer, your solution worked!  Please submit it as an answer formally.  Do you (or anyone else) know why this fixed the error?

Comment: Also, Quasimodo's clone, sorry I haven't created a minimal environment to fix this, but I very much appreciate your tenacity.

Comment: The `click()` method was the first thing I had in my test case. Assuming you *do* want a central listener with a delegated handler in the document, I've played around with `document.on()` to reproduce the error. I managed to do so at best with dirty hacks, not in real situation. It will be too much explaining the differences in a short comment. I'll add it to my answer a short while later. For a good readable Q/A format I propose you place your additional question into your opening question. It would really be interesting to investigate a live example of erroneous behavior e.g. on jsfiddle.

Comment: Why do you not use the `.toggle` method for this? http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: @Eric Baldwin, thanks, I've posted an answer with that.

Comment: In the every js file you have included, check if you have another click event defined, there might be two click events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why, but my days in unobtrusive javascript have taught me to be as specific and as least fuzzy as I can.

Never worried why, as long as it worked. Having been asked why (just here), my answer is "I will have to look it up". Sorry.

Thus, I would avoid setting a catch method on THE document and then filter actions: I would directly point the event catches on the element (or set of elements) I want to watch.

So, instead of using:

```
$(document).on('click','.reportsArrow', function() {
    //...
});
```

I would go the direct way:

```
$('.reportsArrow').click(function () {
    //..
});
```

Having read the API documentation for jQuery `.on()`, it appears to me that it would be probably more suitable to use `.one()` instead, so there is no continuation after hit "#1". But I have not tested it, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: The most clean solution would be to use `.toggle`.

Comment: So, in the OP example: `$('.reportsArrow').toggle('slow');`

Comment: Sure. But my point focuses on targeting, not the actual code block.

Comment: I get that. But it would be a much cleaner solution. Thereby, you are advising to use an old method. We have to figure out **why** the click is fired twice. The `.one` method will work, but this will remove the eventlistener after a click. I guess that's not what he needs because he wants to be able to toggle the div. Probably this behaviour is coming from the use of multiple classes(with the same name) and therefore the `click` will fire more than once(as many times as classes).

Comment: I looked into using .toggle and it would not work in this case because adding `.reportCollapsed` to the parent div does not hide it entirely. Instead, it hides specific elements in the div.  That being said, I am using `toggleClass()` instead of using an if/else branch.

Comment: I bet the script is executed every time the reportsArrow is created.  Because there is only one at a time (the old one is destroyed), the old event gets destroyed with the old reportsArrow.  However, if you use $(document).on( like you are suppose to, and the script gets executed every time the reportsArrow gets created, since the event is on the document, not the arrow, it is not destroyed, and you get another event added to the document.  The second arrow would get two events, the third three, etc.  That is why arrow.click() worked while stopPropegation didn't.

Comment: @RubyRacer You could edit your answer to use `.on` method: `$('.reportsArrow').on('click', function(){});`. @Eric Baldwin I've created a jsFiddle to show why the event fires twice. You are adding a class on click(if it hasn't been set) otherwise you remove it. If you've multiple classes the event will fire multiple times(for every class instance). In my example click the left button first, after that the right one. The last event will fired twice. http://jsfiddle.net/sjEr9/

Comment: @GuyT, The jsFiddle you created doesn't reflect my problem.  In my dev environment, the event is fired exactly twice every time, but on yours, the event is fired once, twice, or three times in a cycle.  This is because you're using `.btnExample` as both the class being added to and removed from the parent and the class of the button being clicked.  As a result, the event is fired once, twice, or three times as `.btnExample` is added to `<body>` and `<html>`.  Compare that with this updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/sjEr9/1/

Comment: All in all, this has been a great help to me.  I really appreciate you all debugging with me over these past few days.

Comment: @GuyT, why update my answer with a synonym? I could also change `$('...')` to `jQuery('...')` and it wouldn't make any difference. I repeat, my point is on targeting.

Answer (score 6):

The event would be getting fired more then once and propagated up-ward in the `DOM` tree. Use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/). You can also use the [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead of branching.

```
$(document).on('click','.commonClass', function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('newClass');
});
```

Comment: and use toggleClass as @Milind suggested

Comment: You still need `stopPropagation` even with `toggleClass`.

Comment: This did not work, the toggle and `console.log` output still happen twice.

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop event propogation to child elements.also you can use toggleClass instead:

```
$(document).on('click','.commonClass', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('newClass') 
});
```

Comment: This did not work, the toggle and `console.log` output still happens twice.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

You need to avoid event bubbling up the DOM tree. There must be a parent causing the event to fire twice or more time.
To avoid this use [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```
$(document).on('click','.commonClass', function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('newClass');

});
```

Comment: This did not work, the toggle and `console.log` output still happen twice.

Comment: Here: http://pastie.org/private/5orlaofafv3wpx73xw3ndq  The class I'm toggling is `reportsArrow`.  I should point out that this toggles correctly in the mockups created by the web designer.

Comment: You mean the click event is on `reportsArrow`? And where is the script for `toggleClass` and `console log`

Comment: Ah, yes.  It is the `commonClass`.  New pastie with the script: http://pastie.org/private/napvctifydbsr7hjzycxrg

Comment: Where is the code for click event?Show your actual code

Comment: It should be in the second pastie at the bottom.  The commented out code is my original code and the suggested version is not commented out.  Either way, the `console.log` output is shown twice.

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/ws4N5/, just works once. I cant predict why it is twice at your side

Comment: I know.  When the designer created it using just HTML and JS, it worked too.  There is something Rails related causing this problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55885/discussion-between-eric-baldwin-and-shaunakde).

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce your problem. Your code is working fine in my Firefox on a simple HTML page.

Please try this piece of code and come back with the console output:

```
function onClick(ev) {
  console.log(ev.currentTarget, '\n', ev.target, '\n', ev);
  if(ev.target === ev.currentTarget)
    console.log($(this).parent().toggleClass('newClass').hasClass('newClass') ? 'B' : 'A');
};
```

EDIT:
and of course:

```
$(document).on('click', '.commonClass', onClick);
```

Comment: I've added the console output to this pastie: http://pastie.org/private/debepje1y7jurmhpuo4ng Note, every example of `reports.js?body=<some value>` refers to the line number of code executed and comes from Google Chrome, not js itself

Answer (score 1):

For readability put the logic into the jQuery selector using the `:not` like this

```
$(document).on('click','.reportCollapsed > .reportsArrow', function() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass('reportCollapsed')
  console.log("A");
})

$(document).on('click','not:(.reportCollapsed) > .reportsArrow', function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('reportCollapsed')
  console.log("B");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that this works one time (click > else > B) could it be that something listens for DOMSubtreeModified or other DOMChange Events which again trigger a click on the document ?

Have you tried debugging/following the calls after the inital click? Afaik chrome has a nice gui to do this.